# Mac に Homebrew がインストールできない

Tags: macos, homebrew

以下を入力すると既にインストール済みとなります。

```
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to
reinstall you should do the following before running this installer
again:
```

なのでアンインストールを試みると以下となってしまいます。

```
> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"

 Failed to locate Homebrew!
```

brewコマンドはnot foundになってしまいます。

```
> brew -v
-bash: brew: command not found
```

ご存じの方がいらしたらご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: それでは、`cd /usr/local/bin`を入力すると、`brew`という実行ファイル、見えますか。見えるなら、`$PATH`という環境変数を入力すると、`PATH`の出力にて、`/usr/local/bin`も含まれていますか。

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/brew`とフルパスで実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。/usr/local/bin/にはbrew自体がない状況です。
また`sudo find / -name brew`でも何も見つかりませんでした。
`echo $PATH`の結果は`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`でした。

Comment: 残念ですねー！ええと、`brew`がないのに、残ってしまったファイルもあるかもしれません。[この投稿によると](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22544141)、フォルダー削除の方が良いかもしれません・・・特に`/usr/local/Cellar`と`/usr/local/.git`。（言うまでもないことですが、`rm -rf`のコマンドを実行する前に、フォルダーをチェックした方がいいと思います。必要なファイルがないように、などー）

Comment: ありがとうございます。`/usr/local/Cellar`はなかったのですが`/usr/local/.git`を消去することで、brewのインストールが動作しました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントで述べた通り、この場合の解決策は：

1. `brew`自体があるかどうか試してみて、mamamaさんの`sudo find / -name brew`のコマンドを使いましょう。
2. 何も見つからない場合は、[iiiさんの投稿](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22544141/1167750)によると、`/usr/local/Cellar`や`/usr/local/.git`というフォルダーを消去した方が良いかもしれません。

> ご注意：消去する前に、上記のフォルダーをチェックした方が良いと思います。大切なファイルを消去しないように。

3. 上記のフォルダーを本当に消去したいなら、`rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar`と`rm -rf /usr/local/.git`というコマンドを実行してください。

今は、[`brew`のインストール](http://brew.sh/)をもう一度試してみてください。